# Can I select Content Type in Alfresco drag and drop upload?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco 4.2.1 both the Flash uploader and the HTML uploader enables users to select a content-type, but not the drag-and-drop uploader. How do I get the same options regarding content-type selection in the drag-and-drop uploader as I get in the Flash and HTML uploaders?

I have modified dnd-upload.get.js to include the following code:

```
model.contentTypes = [
{
   id: "proj:drawing",
   value: "type.proj_drawing"
},{
   id: "proj:doc",
   value: "type.proj_doc"
}];
```

But I can not see any options to select ContentType, not during upload or after upload.

Answer (score 0):

flash-upload.get.js under
 share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/upload/

We need to add out custom content type in the list of content Types. In this case our custom content type is “custom:Product”.

```
function getContentTypes()
{
 var contentTypes = [
{
  id: "cm:content",
  value: "cm_content"
  },
 {
  id: " custom:Product",
  value: " custom:Product"
   }];
 return contentTypes;
}
model.contentTypes = getContentTypes()
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine for flash-upload and html-upload but I want that functionality in dnd-upload. I'v modified both flash-upload and dnd-upload but it does not seem to work. Does that code work for you in the drag-and-drop upload aswell as the flash upload?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but this feature is intentionally not available for drag and drop file uploads. You may still change the content type manually *after* the file has been uploaded, but not prior.

Here's a bug report that was submitted a couple versions back by a user that goes into detail as to why this functionality is missing: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-11350

**Update**

I just wanted to add that, as of Alfresco Community 4.0b, any ability to enable selecting custom content types for drag and drop uploads has been removed from the codebase. It *may* be possible to make some modifications to other files and achieve this, but not by configuration alone.